# Average of 3 numbers comes out wrong

Tags: python, average, calculator

I want to find the average for 3 numbers inputted by the user.

```
    val1, val2, val3 = int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3])

    print val1, val2, val3

    avr = ((val1 + val2 + val3) / 3)
    print avr
    print "%02.f" % avr
```

Given the 3 numbers 60, 39 and 92 and by typing `python.exe calculator.py 60 39 92` in the terminal, I get:

Output:

```
60 39 92
63
63.00
```

The output should show an average of 63.67, not 63.00. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: val1, val2, val3 and 3 are all integers, so the final result will also be integer too. try dividing by 3.0, which is a float

Answer (score 3):

In python 2, trying to divide with ints will always produce an int, even if the result would normally be a float. The solution to this is to cast the ints to floating-point numbers (a fundamentally different datatype) instead, OR use `3.0` instead of `3` (as the former is read as a float and the latter is an integer):

```
val1, val2, val3 = float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])
```

or

```
avg = (val1 + val2 + val3) / 3.0
```

When all numbers involved are floats instead of ints, then the result will be a float.

---

If you were to use python 3 (which you should; python2 is no longer officially supported), this would be a non-issue: integer division has its own operator, `//`, and this type of operation will always produce a float if the answer wouldn't be an integer.

Comment: You just need the denominator to be float. In Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

You input variables as an integer, then the average result will be integer, too.
Then you print it as float, that's where you are wrong.
If you still want float result, try:

`val1, val2, val3 = float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])`

Comment: Ah yes I can't believe I couldn't catch that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, if you divide an integer by another integer, it results in an integer. You can divide by a float to fix this:

```py
avr = (val1 + val2 + val3) / 3.0
```